# conditional types for nav item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I would like to define my interface so that when you give a nav that is a navigationItem, you can optionally give childs for a dropdown. when the childs property is given I would like to enforce the icon property of the navigationItem.
When no childs property are given the icon property should not be given.

Any idea on how I could achieve that ?

this is my current interface

```
interface dropdown {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition;
}
interface navigationItem {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition; // only needed if the childs is given
  childs?: dropdown[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using two different Interfaces like this.

Have one with

```
interface Type1 {
    name: string;
    href: string;
    childs: never;
}
```

The second one will be

```
interface Type2 {
    name: string;
    href: string;
    childs: dropdown[];
    icon: IconDefinition;
}
```

Then you can use both the types using a conditional like this

```
value: Type1 | Type2
```

Why this works is, when you add `icon: never` to `Type1`, you can only have `name` and `href` keys.

So if someone adds the `childs` key, then the type becomes `Type2` which needs to have `icon` given as well.

So, if `const a: Type1 | Type2 = { name: '', href: '', childs: [] };`, it throws

```
Type '{ name: string; href: string; childs: []; }' is not assignable to type 'Type1 | Type2'.
Property 'icon' is missing in type '{ name: string; href: string; childs: dropdown[]; }' but required in type 'Type2'.
```

If you want to use a single type instead, define a new type like this.

```
type Type3 = Type1 | Type2;
```

Then use it like this

```
const a: Type3;
```

Comment: Hi, not really because I want to set the type of icon's depending or whether the optional childs are given. your thing does only give optional type for one item not depending on the other one

Comment: From the question, it seems like you just need to have `icon` passed when you have `childs` present otherwise both can be absent. Is that not what you needed ? If not please update the question. I am a but confused.

Comment: @MaximeGhéraille Have updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: thx, I see what you mean but isn't it possible without saying value: type1 | type2 ? I would like to keep it value: type2 and that is automatically know that the childs is given so the icon should too

Comment: @MaximeGhérailleI have updated my answer. Check it out. You can create a new Type with `type Type3 = Type1 | Type2;` and then use the new type

Comment: i tried what you said but my it keeps erroring 'Type '{ name: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'navigationType'.
  Type '{ name: string; href: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'navigationItem': icon, childs'. it keeps thinking that it is a type2 when i dont give a childs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232418/discussion-between-nisanth-reddy-and-maxime-gheraille).